# rundeck - api - ansible - uri - Add Key passwd - Value not good

Tags: api, curl, ansible, postman, rundeck

I try to add a new key password, facing the issue with the API. The key is successfully created. But, when is used is not good value.

I try to generate the key with Postman, and the key is created but the value is not correct. When I use the same value manually on the interface then it works fine.

1. I deleted before the key (manually)
2. postman:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://rundeck.dev.xxxxxx.com/api/11/storage/keys/project_name/gitlab?authtoken=FdMORu02flT2R5zI' \
--header 'Content-type: application/x-rundeck-data-password' \
--header 'Cookie: AWSALB=D6Kpid4U/o7uHy9G0Pg40uvILs1toq367tPzPiCskEha7YGM3eCJldNnKyMFYBrkwOXIyvVmKAsIe9yIRm/8xOX/0mj4LIRy2wMl3qYpOvXKw3x9e+rXnjd8gEjX; AWSALBCORS=D6Kpid4U/o7uHy9G0Pg40uvILs1toq367tPzPiCskEha7YGM3eCJldNnKyMFYBrkwOXIyvVmKAsIe9yIRm/8xOX/0mj4LIRy2wMl3qYpOvXKw3x9e+rXnjd8gEjX' \
--data-raw 'XKmB1wkjsdfikjkHkKwCEW'
```

I try to add SCM with the key generated but still is not working. However, when I create manually the key with the same name and value the SCM import is working.

I have the same error with ansible with URI.

1. I deleted before the key (manually)
2. I create a playbook to access rundeck API

```
    - name: "Create Keys {{ project_name }} - gitlab"
      uri:
        url: "{{ RD_URL }}{{ API_11 }}/storage/keys/{{ project_name }}/gitlab?authtoken={{ RD_TOKEN }}"
        method: POST
        body_format: raw
        validate_certs: no
        status_code: [201, 409]
        return_content: true
        headers:
          Content-Type: application/x-rundeck-data-password
          X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: "{{ RD_TOKEN }}"
        body: '{{ GITLAB_TOKEN }}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the password via API 40 and Rundeck 3.4.9 with the following call:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# protocol
protocol="http"

# basic rundeck info
rdeck_host="localhost"
rdeck_port="4440"
rdeck_api="40"
rdeck_token="hcFPFbJHFIqerwaRsWtuhPnPAIUoY4Kt"

# api call
curl --location --request POST "$protocol://$rdeck_host:$rdeck_port/api/$rdeck_api/storage/keys/mypass" \
  --header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: $rdeck_token" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/x-rundeck-data-password" \
  --data-raw "12345"
```

Also, I created a Job example to test the password content:

```yaml
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 5658bb13-f9e9-494b-839c-d18f25057a4e
  loglevel: INFO
  name: HelloWorld
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  options:
  - name: opt1
    secure: true
    storagePath: keys/mypass
    valueExposed: true
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: null
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: echo ${option.opt1}
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 5658bb13-f9e9-494b-839c-d18f25057a4e
```

Running the job, you can see the password value.

Also [tested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuR2H.jpg) using the SCM config.

So, make sure that you're pointing to the right key in your SCM config and ensure to use the latest API version (40 at this moment) in your API Call.